# Classification of contractible 4-manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Is there a general homeomorphism classification of contractible topological 4-manifolds (possibly with boundary or noncompact)?

In the compact case, any such manifold has a homology 3-sphere as its boundary (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur_manifold)). Homology 3-spheres can be [classified](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4798/classification-of-homology-3-spheres) (via geometrization of 3-manifolds), so maybe there is hope for a classification of the interiors also.

Comment: It's not even really possible for 3-manifolds, so there's no hope in dimension 4. Actually, can you even do it in the compact case? I'm pretty skeptical. Nobody even knows yet which homology 3-spheres bound contractible manifolds (only some special cases), and it's not clear that they ever will (depending maybe on what "which ones" means).

Comment: @MikeMiller When you say that it isn’t really possible for 3-manifolds, do you mean “we don’t have a clue” or “there’s enough evidence to suggest that there is no reasonable classification”?

Comment: @Santana [The latter](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1993684?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you work in topological category and assume that your manifolds are compact then any two compact contractible 4-manifolds $W_1, W_2$ with homeomorphic boundaries $\partial W_1, \partial W_2$ are homeomorphic. This follows for instance from the main classification result of Richard Stong:

R. Stong, Simply-connected 4-manifolds with a given boundary. 
Topology Appl. 52 (1993), no. 2, 161–167.

Roughly speaking, Stong extended Freedman's classification theorem to the case of compact simply-connected 4-manifolds with boundary.

(The special case of contractible manifolds might have been known earlier, I am not sure.)

Thus, if you think that 3-dimensional integer homology spheres are "classified" then so are compact topological contractible 4-manifolds. 
(Personally I regard the classification problem of integer homology spheres which are hyperbolic 3-manifolds to be hopelessly complicated. But modulo this problem, yes, we "know" what 3-dimensional homology spheres are.) Of course, a classification up to diffeomorphism of smooth 4-manifolds with the given boundary is well beyond reach at this point.

Comment: My comments above are foolish, as they refer to the differentiable category. Of course, Freedman proved that every integer homology 3-sphere bounds a contractible *topological* 4-manifold. Thank you for posting this.