# Non-Compact Topological Four-Manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

I know there exists a complete classification of non-compact surfaces and some work has been done on non-compact three-manifolds, but is anything known about non-compact topological four-manifolds?

Comment: Even the 3-manifold case is totally unclear. There is a continuum of open 3-dimensional connected contractible manifolds. I am not sure which work you have in mind.There are some recent, very tentative, results on geometrizing open 3-manifolds. Maybe you assume that your 4-manifold are tame? Then at least the simply-connected case is reasonably well-understood. See Stong's work mentioned here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3108922/classification-of-contractible-4-manifolds/3111908#3111908